# Python POST function returns 200 But does not POST anything to POSTGRES

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, jinja2

I am currently trying to register a user using an html form. The inputs of the user will then be taken by the ajax function and sent as a json object in the flask server.

The json object will be received by a Python POST function which parses the data and saves it in a database using a stored function. The Python POST function works alright because I tested with POSTMAN.

This displays the registration form:

```
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

while this does the processing of the user's input:

```
@app.route('/registration', methods=['POST'])
    def registration():
        jsonobject = request.get_json()
        username = jsonobject['username']
        password = jsonobject['password']

        res = spcall("newcounselor", (username, password),True)

        if 'Error' in str(res[0][0]):
            return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': res[0][0]})
        return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'message': res[0][0]})
```

To push the data from the html form to the python function above, I use this AJAX post function which I assigned as onclick value in the button of the html form:

```
<script>
        function register() {
            var username = $('#inputUsername').val();
            var password = $('#inputPassword').val();

            var jsonobject = JSON.stringify({"username":username,
                "password":password
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/registration",
                data: jsonobject,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    <!-- window.location.replace('/login')-->
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj){
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                        "Basic " + btoa("xenia:Incorrect"));
            }
            })

        }
    </script>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- surrounded my spcall with try-exception
- checked if javascript gets the data from the form (it does!)
- checked if Python post function is working (it is! checked it using
  POSTMAN)
- checked if spcall is working (it is!)
- I changed jsonobject = request.get_json() to jsonobject =
  request.get_json(*force=True*)

**But still it is not working. It only returns a status code of 200 but does not add anything to the postgres database. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You would get a `KeyError` if `jsonobject` in `registration` were empty.  So something must be going wrong in `spcall`.  I'd suggest logging the value of `res` to see what's going on.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've already tried that and its ok; also, I think it will not submit the form if there are empty inputs.....

Comment: @Mantis You better wrap your *spcall* with a **try-except-else** block. That's the right way for error handling in Python (or any programming language on earth). I'm sure it would solve your problem. Read http://geek-university.com/python/the-try-except-else-statements/ to know more about try-except-else.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I tried it. Still returns a 200 response but not adding anything to my postgres db

Comment: Did you print out 'username' and 'password' in 'registration' function? Are you sure the data is there?

Comment: @metmirr ... yes,.. I have used postman to check its functionality. The username and password is pushed to the python function registration() by ajax after the user clicks on the login button.